# Pad array with zeros- openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

How to pad an array(`cv::Mat`) with zeros in OpenCV?

Comment: what do you mean by padding in this context?

Comment: @juanchopanza I mean making a bigger array with zeros around the original array.

Comment: Can't you make an array full of zeros, and then fill the relevant block with data from the smaller array?

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm sure that would work, I just don't know how to do that! If you do, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a way to do it

```
cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat padded;
int padding = 3;
padded.create(img.rows + 2*padding, img.cols + 2*padding, img.type());
padded.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));

img.copyTo(padded(Rect(padding, padding, img.cols, img.rows)));
```

Comment: You need to switch between the rows and cols in the `Rect`. This is the function declaration `Rect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height)`

Answer (score 29):

An another way to pad an image is to use [copyMakeBorder](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder) function:

```
 C++: void copyMakeBorder(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int top, int bottom, int left, int right, int borderType, const Scalar& value=Scalar() )
```

Then padding with zeros is simply like that

```
Mat image,image_pad;
copyMakeBorder(image,image_pad,1,1,1,1,BORDER_CONSTANT,Scalar(0));
```

Finally, here is the tutorial of [Adding borders to your images](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html).