# opencv: change image size without effecting content size

Tags: image, opencv, resize

I am getting image containing character after applying my image process. All these images (having character as content) have different size. I want to resize all images in same size without effecting it's content size. see below image:

http://techsture.com/img.jpg

I have tried some function to merge my source image with other white image but it needs both source images with same size. I need common size of images for further process.

Please guide me how can I convert my images to common size ??

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pad array with zeros- openCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737831/pad-array-with-zeros-opencv)

Answer (score 4):

I would make a new image with the destination size, set a ROI in this new image to where you want the source image to show. Then use cvResize.
It should look something like:

```
int newWidth = 100;
int newHeight = 100;
CvRect rect;

IplImage* source = cvLoadImage("c:/myimage");
IplImage* dest = cvCreateImage(cvSize(newWidth,newHeight),source->depth,source->nChannels);

rect.x = newWidth/2 - source->width/2;
rect.y = newHeight/2 - source->height/2;
rect.width = source->width;
rect.height = source->height;

cvSetImageROI(dest,rect);
cvResize(source,dest);
cvResetImageROI(dest);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Your method seems to work, though in OpenCV 2.0+ the method from the linked thread (arguably) reads better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737831/pad-array-with-zeros-opencv

Comment: cvGetRectSubPix is also an option.