# Pad a Mat kernel with zeros to the size of Image

Tags: c++, opencv, filtering

Using OpenCv in cpp

i need to increase the size of the given Mat kernel to the size of any given image by padding it with extra zeroes.

```
Mat kernel = (Mat_<double>(3,3) <<  1.36, 0.062,  -0.921,
        -0.644198,  1.10, -0.17,
        -0.072951, -1.81485,  2.806);
```

I found the way in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737831/pad-array-with-zeros-opencv) to pad the whole array with zeroes but i want to save the values in kernel as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is as simple as below.

```
// this is the input image  
cv::Mat img(100, 100, CV_64FC1);

cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.36, 0.062, -0.921,
    -0.644198, 1.10, -0.17,
    -0.072951, -1.81485, 2.806);

cv::Mat kernelNew = cv::Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_64FC1);
kernel.copyTo(kernelNew(cv::Rect(0, 0, kernel.cols, kernel.rows)));
kernel = kernelNew;
```